# Is it relevant to apply BLEU and TER metrics to a domain specific chatbot built with GPT-3?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have been told by my teacher that I may want to use these, however I am afraid they are not compatible with the wide range of possible valid answers, in the end. Despite the Question Answering (QA) purpose of the bot.

Also maybe part of the problem is that I struggle to find documentation on these metrics, especially TER. I do not even know what it stands for.

BLEU = Bilingual Evaluation Understudy
TER = Translation Error Rate

Comment: Maybe you can give details/links for the abbreviations used?